# Terraform complex variable definition

Tags: terraform

**The Context:**
let me start saying I know "flat is better than nested" but in this case using flat variable structure lacks of semanatics so I created a nested structure as follows:

```
users-config = [
{
    team = "team1"
    custom-policies = [
        {
            policy-name = "p1"
            policy-json = "<some long text in json>"
        },
        {
            policy-name = "p2"
            policy-json = "<some long text in json>"
        }
    ]
    groups = [
        {
            group-name = "g1"
            policies-attached = ["p1", "p2"]
        }
    ]
    users = [
        {
            name = "u1"
            user-name = "user.name"
            email = "user-name@example.com"
            groups = ["g1"]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

This shows the policies, groups and users created for a specific team.

**The Challenge**:
Creating this structure in terraform variable definition is quite simple, basically (many fields ommited):

```
variable "users-configf" {
type = list(object(
    {
        team = string
        custom-policies = list(object({...}))
        groups = list(object({...}))
        users = list(object({...}))
    }
))
}
```

But I have been using different combination of for_each / for expressions and I have not achieved traverse over this structure to create the resources. Basically I will pick some pieces from the structure to create the resources (at least that's my intention obviously code is not working):

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "test-groups" {

  for_each = [for uc in var.users-config: for g in uc.groups: g.group-name]
  name = each.value
}
```

**The Expectation**: I would traverse the structure and create the resources as needed (groups, policies, users, user-group membership and policies-groups attachments)

As I mentioned at the begining of the question, I can achieve this by creating flat variable definitions for users, groups, policies and creating the bindings between them but I'm looking for a descriptive variable.  Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the shape of your input, the key requirement for `for_each` is that the map you assign to it must have one element per instance you want to create, and so you can either pre-flatten the data structure at the source, or you can write some Terraform expressions to derive several differently-flattened data structures from your original nested data structure.

The common way to flatten data structures in Terraform is to use [the `flatten` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html), whose documentation includes the section [Flattening nested structures for `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each).

For example, we can use `flatten` to build a flat list of all of the groups across all of the `users-config` elements like this:

```
locals {
  all_groups = flatten([
    for idx, config in var.users_config : [
      for g in config.groups : merge(
        g,
        { users_config_index = idx },
      )
    ]
  ])
}
```

The result of the above would be a list like the following, given the input you showed in your question:

```
[
  {
    group_name         = "g1"
    policies_attached  = ["p1", "p2"]
    users_config_index = 0
  },
]
```

To make this compatible with the expectations of `for_each` it will need one final transform into a map which has a unique key for each of the elements. If you know that your group names will be unique across all of the user config elements then you could just use the `group_name` values directly, but if not then you'll need to combine the `users_config_index` with the `group_name` to make them all unique:

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for grp in local.all_groups : "${grp.users_config_index}:${grp.group_name}" => grp
  }
 
  name = each.value.group_name
  path = "/groups/${each.value.users_config_index}"
}
```

Note that by including a list index in the key you make the instances subject to changes if the ordering of the items in the list is changed later, so I would suggest avoiding including the indices in the keys if possible but I've shown it here only to make a more complete example that covers all of the decisions that go into `for_each` usage.